# Is it possible to change format of date stored in a shell variable?

Tags: oracle, bash, shell

So I am using a command to get dates from my database.

```
date1=$(sqlplus -s $1/$2@$3 <<EOF
set heading OFF termout ON trimout ON feedback OFF
set pagesize 0
select DATE from data_table where type='B_DATE';
exit;
EOF)
```

echoing the date gives the following value.

```
02-JUN-14   12.30.00.000000 PM
```

when I try to change format of this date, using

```
bdate=$(date -d "$date1" +"%A %d-%m-%Y")
```

I get the error

```
date: invalid date `02-JUN-14 12.30.00.000000 PM'
```

Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong and how to correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to replace some `.` by `:` :

```
date='02-JUN-14 12.30.00.000000 PM'; date=$(echo "$date" | sed -re 's/([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/\1:\2:\3/'); echo $date;date -d "$date" +"%A %d-%m-%Y"
02-JUN-14 12:30:00.000000 PM
Monday 02-06-2014
```

Take a look at how I transformed the date format with sed.